# How to insert multiple row in dynamoDb using PHP?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have written below Json for insert in dynamodb, but unable to insert. But if I try single element without array it's working fine.

```
    $item = $marshaler->marshalJson('
    [
        {
            "PK":"CATG",
            "SK":"NAME#SMART_PHONE",
            "TYPE":"CATG",
            "ATTR":{
                "name":"安いスマートフォン一覧【最安値比較】"
            }
        },
        {
            "PK":"CATG#SMART_PHONE",
            "SK":"SUBCATG#IPHONE",
            "TYPE":"SUBCATG",
            "ATTR":{
                "name":"IPHONE",
                "Compa":"mac",
                "uid":123
            }
        },
        {
            "PK":"CATG#SMART_PHONE#SUBCATG#IPHONE",
            "SK":"PROD#PHONE11",
            "TYPE":"PROD",
            "ATTR":{
                "name":"PHONE11",
                "uid":123,
                "price":112.02,
                "images":[
                    
                ],
                "total":120
            }
        },
        {
            "PK":"CATG#SMART_PHONE#SUBCATG#IPHONE",
            "SK":"PROD#PHONE7",
            "TYPE":"PROD",
            "ATTR":{
                "name":"PHONE7",
                "Compa":"mac",
                "uid":124,
                "price":102.02,
                "images":[
                    
                ],
                "total":80
            }
        }
    ]
');

$params = [
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'Item' => $item
];
$result = $dynamodb->putItem($params);
```

After apply this code.
I have got below error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: The JSON document must be valid and be an object at its root. in E:\xampp\htdocs\shop\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\DynamoDb\Marshaler.php:99 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\shop\item.php(30): Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler->marshalJson('\r\n [\r\n ...') #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\shop\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\DynamoDb\Marshaler.php on line 99
```

If I insert single row it's working fine. How can I insert bulk row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert multiple items you have two options:

1. you can have a loop and repeatedly call the `PutItem` API for each one
2. you can break up your collection of items into groups of up to 25 and use the `BatchWriteItem` API ([see docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html))

Note that the BatchWriteItem API will still result in 25 WCU being used but it just saves you a bit on the network round-trips, making fewer calls.

The downside of using `BatchWriteItem` is that you have to manage the grouping of items and then handle the partial successful writes, such that unsuccessful items get re-grouped/re-tried.